# Bitcoin not received since 3days now

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info

[image]

Two different bitcoin payment was sent I sent into one Wallet Address requested, But only one came into my wallet successfully. But I am yet to receive the second one, and when I try to look it up on blockchain explorer. The only information that comes up, is the bitcoin that came in successfully, But nothing can be found about the second transaction.

Answer (score 2):

You should call their support. They did not make the payment that receipt says that they made.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot....I hope they will have it fixed, because I have really been bothered and been trying to call and message them, But no response yet...Am worried.